# Why are there no gpg signed hashes for the mini.iso

Tags: security, iso, gnupg, hash, signature

None of the gpg-signed files I've found containing hashes for various ubuntu iso files contain a hash for the mini.iso files. The only hashes for the mini.iso files I've found are plain md5sums on the same page with the links to the files themselves: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

That page is at least https. As far as I can tell, the actual files don't even have that minimal protection. Really, guys, I hope you'll point me toward a page I'm missing with gpg signed hashes, preferably one that accepts https. Because if not, this is really rather lame for late 2016 don't you think? Md5sums were shown to be insecure several years ago and even if we ignore that, why on earth are these excluded  from the gpg-signed lists? Please tell me I'm overlooking something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu always provides signed hash files on the download servers. Within each image-directory, there are several hash files with corresponding signatures. An example listing for [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS AMD64](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/installer-amd64/current/images/):

```
[ ]     MANIFEST        2016-08-10 19:07    1.0K
[ ]     MANIFEST.udebs  2016-08-10 19:07    23K
[ ]     MD5SUMS         2016-08-10 19:07    3.0K
[ ]     MD5SUMS.gpg     2016-08-10 19:07    933
[ ]     SHA1SUMS        2016-08-10 19:07    3.3K
[ ]     SHA1SUMS.gpg    2016-08-10 19:07    933
[ ]     SHA256SUMS      2016-08-10 19:07    4.2K
[ ]     SHA256SUMS.gpg  2016-08-10 19:07    933
[DIR]   cdrom/          2016-08-10 19:07    -
[DIR]   hd-media/       2016-08-10 19:07    -
[DIR]   netboot/        2016-08-10 19:07    -
[ ]     udeb.list       2016-08-10 19:07    4.3K
```

The `minimal.iso` file is stored in the `netboot` directory.

Comment: Indeed, Those files have it. I kept finding others of the same name, like the ones here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/  that don't. Startpage (like Google with less evil) failed me. Thanks.